# Calculating the Q-point of this NMOS

Tags: transistors

Let the following circuit with \$ V_{DD} = 3.3V R_D = 10k \Omega, R1 = 140k \Omega, R_2 = 60k\Omega, R_{Si} = 4k\Omega ,V_{TN} = 0.4V , K_n = 0.5 \frac{
mA}{V^2} , \lambda = 0.02V^{-1} \$
[image]

so we put ourself in the DC mode and suppose the transistor is in saturation mode so we get : \$V_{GS_Q} = \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} V_{DD} \$ and \$I_{DQ} = K_n(V_{GS_Q} - V_{TN})^2\$ and \$V_{DS_Q} = V_DD - R_D \cdot I_{DQ} \$
are these the formulas i will use to calculate the coordinates needed for the Q-Point?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: im asking are the equations i gave are enough to calculate the Q-point coordinates?

Comment: Yes, you have all..

Comment: Thanks again @G36